# Rails 3.2.13 Association destroy. Listing image records destroyed but image files aren't removed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I have a `User` model, `listing` model, and `listing_images` model.

User model:

```
has_many :listings, dependent: :destroy
has_many :listing_images, through: listings
```

Listing model:

```
has_many :listing_images, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :user
```

Listing_image:

```
belongs_to :listing
belongs_to :user
```

When a user deletes their listing, I want to also remove the images associated to the listing. When destroy is called on the listing the `listing_images` records are removed from the database but the files are still there.

As a test, I remove a user to see if it will remove the profile image, which works fine.

Am I missing something?

Comment: From your comment that "the files are still there", I am assuming you have some sort of upload file logic that places files into your file system? If so, you need to wire up the destroy action on the image model to also remove the files.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using jQuery file upload. So you are saying when destroying an image association, it doesn't remove the files along with the records?

Comment: Rails has no idea the files exist on the disk, only you do. Rails can take care of database entries but your code logic has to handle removing the files.

Comment: @theTinMan When I delete a user, their profile image is removed as well. Is it because it isn't an association? (User model has profile_image field to store the name)

Comment: I am pretty sure that you don't use jquery for fileupoad but some gem like Carrierwave or Paperclip?

Answer (score 0):

In your `listing_image` model:

```
before_destroy :remove_image_file

def remove_image_file
  # put logic here to get image path from db record and remove image file
end
```